# How to reassign a struct value with a function in solidity

Tags: struct, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I am trying to change the value of a boolean in the struct to toggle the accessibility of a function. But after the function runs it seems not to be reassigning the boolean value.I tried replacing the boolean with an enum since its only two inputs but it still doesn't work. How do i do this.

```
        struct Hotel{
            uint256 roomNo;
            string suiteLevel;
            bool isOccupied;    
        }

        enum Status{
            Vacant,
            Occupied
        }
        Hotel[] public hotelroomsarray; 

        function newhotel(uint256 _num, string calldata _str, bool _isoccupied) public {
            Hotel memory room = Hotel(_num, _str, _isoccupied);
            hotelroomsarray.push(room);
        }-------i pass in false into this function

        function bookroom1() public payable uptofee{
            Hotel memory booked = hotelroomsarray[0];                   
            require(booked.isOccupied == false, "This room is alraeady occupied");              
            payable(owner).transfer(msg.value); 
            booked.isOccupied = true;------------part that isn't working                            
            bookertoroom[msg.sender] = hotelroomsarray[0];
            bookers.push(msg.sender);       
            addrtoamntpaid[msg.sender] = msg.value; 
            count++;                
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are just updating the reference. you have to  update  in the array.

soln:

```
         function bookroom1() public payable uptofee{                  
            require(booked.isOccupied == false, "This room is alraeady occupied");              
            payable(owner).transfer(msg.value); 
            hotelroomsarray[0].isOccupied = true;                          
            bookertoroom[msg.sender] = hotelroomsarray[0];
            bookers.push(msg.sender);       
            addrtoamntpaid[msg.sender] = msg.value; 
            count++;                
        }
```